# ADODB SQL Query ORDER BY subquery not working

Tags: ms-access, vbscript, oledb, adodb

VBScript code in Classic ASP to pull values including a sub-query, ordering by that sub-query doesn't sort. How can I change this query to sort by the subquery results?

Also tried "ORDER BY 2 ASC;" this doesnt throw an error but does nothing

`SELECT tblWP.keyWP, (SELECT SUM(DateDiff('n',tblX.dtmStart,tblX.dtmEnd)) FROM tblX WHERE tblX.keyWP=tblWP.keyWP) AS t1 FROM tblWP ORDER BY t1;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this variation:

```sql
SELECT 
    tblWP.keyWP, 
    Sum(DateDiff('n',tblX.dtmStart,tblX.dtmEnd)) AS t1 
FROM 
    tblWP
INNER JOIN
    tblX
    ON tblWP.keyWP = tblX.keyWPItem
GROUP BY 
    tblWP.keyWP
ORDER BY 
    Sum(DateDiff('n',tblX.dtmStart,tblX.dtmEnd));
```

Comment: I get an aggregate error query does not include keyWP as part of expression. I noticed my initial SQl isnt quite correct, should have been ```tblX.keyWPItem=tblWP.keyWP```

Comment: Added the Group By.

Comment: With Gustav's help I think I have this now. The subquery sorting still remains a mystery and even though my original query works, it doesnt sort. The below code now works as expected;

```SELECT tblWP.keyWP, Sum(DateDiff('n',tblXdtmStart,tblX.dtmEnd)) AS t1
FROM tblWP LEFT JOIN tblX ON tblWP.keyWP = tblX.keyWPItem
GROUP BY tblWP.keyWP
ORDER BY 2;```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    tblWP.keyWP,
    (SELECT SUM(DateDiff('n',tblX.dtmStart,tblX.dtmEnd)) FROM tblX WHERE tblX.keyWP=tblWP.keyWP) AS t1

FROM
    tblWP

ORDER BY
    (SELECT SUM(DateDiff('n',tblX.dtmStart,tblX.dtmEnd)) FROM tblX WHERE tblX.keyWP=tblWP.keyWP)
```